# CWA(dll,api) - C++ macro?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, api, macros

I recently found some interesting macro while browsing random sources around the internet:

```
#define CWA(dll, api)                 ::api
```

Someone can explain me what is that macro and what else it needs to make it works ?
Here is example where its used:

```
CWA(user32, MessageBoxW)(NULL, L"Hello world!", NULL, MB_OK);
```

I think its used to tell to compiler/linker to use some specific import type for APIs or something....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preprocessor language is quite easy to read. You have macro:

```
#define CWA(dll, api) ::api
```

It is used by code:

```
CWA(user32, MessageBoxW)(NULL, L"Hello world!", NULL, MB_OK);
```

So the result of preprocessing is:

```
::MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Hello world!", NULL, MB_OK);
```

Notice that "api" is just second argument of macro, so basically macro has two arguments: first is ignored, second is name of global function (:: is prefix for calling global function, e.g. ::MyGlobalFunc).

First argument "dll" is ignored, so it serves just as comment, in what dll the function is.

Edit: possible reason behind it - somebody wants to clearly document calls to global functions to other DLLs. It nicely reads: "I am calling function MessageBoxW from user32.dll".

Comment: Perhaps a different definition is used sometimes. Or there is a tool which searches the code for CWA uses and analyses or modifies them.

Comment: Alan Stokes: I doubt it - you cannot produce __dllimport from usage, and it's hard to see usage of tracking of calls such as MessageBox? It would have to be really powerful tool. And different definition? It's already MessageBoxW, not generic MessageBox, so I can't see "other definition" possibility.